# Evernote web-only data export

Tags: evernote, export

I need to export my data from Evernote, but don't have Windows or Mac. All information regarding exporting rely on the "free" desktop clients, but they don't run on my systems, only Mac and Windows.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux:

1. The official Evernote Linux client is now available as a beta version. You may try that.
2. You can use one of several unofficial Evernote Linux clients that use Evernote servers, data etc. Nixnote is my favorite as a lightweight client.